# 'setValue' method is not working in Angular application

Tags: angular

I am developing a web application using MEAN Stack with Angular 6. There I have a button in my html to get default values when I click that button it should fill the form field with the default value. Here is my html form.

```
    <div style="float: right" id="extrudedHeightPanel" *ngIf="isExtrudedHeight" name="extrudedHeight">
      <form #extrudedHeightForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveExtrudedHeightValue(extrudedHeightForm)" #form="ngForm">
        <nb-card class="action-buttons">
          <div class="form-input-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="">
                <button type='button' (click)="setDefaultValues()" class="btn btn-sm btn-rectangle btn-default text-case">Restore Default</button>
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-rectangle btn-default text-case">Done</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nb-card>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Extruded Height</p>
        <br>
        <div class="form group">
          Extruded Height:
          <input type="text" nbInput name="extrudedHeight" [(ngModel)]="extrudedHeight" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I got the data from mongo db to my .ts file and tried to set value to the form field using 'setValue' method in Angular. 
.ts file

```
    class{

        extrudedHeightForm: FormGroup;
        ngOnInit()
        {
        this.extrudedHeightForm = new FormGroup({
              extrudedHeight: new FormControl()
            });
        }

                  //Set default values for extrudedHeight
                  setDefaultValues() {
                    this.extrudedHeightService.getExtrudedHeight("default").subscribe(data => {
                      this.extrudedHeightForm.setValue({
                        extrudedHeight:data['extrudedHeight']
                      });
                    });
                  }

   }
```

My question is the following part is not working. Am I gone wrong or is there any method to achieve my requirement.

```
this.extrudedHeightForm.setValue({
                            extrudedHeight:data['extrudedHeight']
                          });
```

--UPDATED--
When I changed into `this.extrudedHeightForm.get('extrudedHeight').setValue(data['extrudedHeight']);`
as suggested in the answer it does not work either. To check the value I printed a console.log.
'console.log(this.extrudedHeightForm.get('extrudedHeight'));' part gives the following values.
[image: Value]

But the value 250 does not show in the form field.

Comment: does patchValue() work? https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value

Comment: it doesn't work but what does it do? nothing? has the value of data['extrudedHeight'] changed? is the subscribe block firing?

Comment: patch value does not work either

Comment: @danday74 the value of data['extrudedHeight'] is same. When I try to debug I cannot set even a break point to 'extrudedHeight:data['extrudedHeight']' line as well

Comment: if the value is the same then when you set the value nothing is going to change. Use console.log if you cannot set a break point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when init the formcontrol, I think you need to give it a hint of its type, such as:

```
       this.extrudedHeightForm = new FormGroup({
          extrudedHeight: new FormControl('')
        });
```

The following code should work for you (i've deleted some nonessential parts):

```
    <div style="float: right" id="extrudedHeightPanel" >
    <form [formGroup]="extrudedHeightForm"  (ngSubmit)="saveExtrudedHeightValue(extrudedHeightForm)">
      <div class="">
        <button type='button' (click)="setDefaultValues()" class="btn btn-sm btn-rectangle btn-default text-case">Restore Default</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Extruded Height</p>
      <br>
      <div>
        Extruded Height:

        <input type="text" formControlName="extrudedHeight" [(ngModel)]="extrudedHeightForm.extrudedHeight"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, please see if it helps this time.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
this.extrudedHeightForm.get('extrudedHeight').setValue(data['extrudedHeight']);
```

You should set value on FormControl, not on FormGroup.

Comment: thanks for yor suggestion. I applied it but did not work. I updated the question according to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using two completely different forms. In your template you have a template-driven form, whereas in your TS you have a reactive form, so of course when you set a value in your `FormControl` it will not reflect in your view. You need to actually use your reactive form in your template. Here's a simplified version:

```html
<form [formGroup]="extrudedHeightForm">
  <input formControlName="extrudedHeight" />
</form>
```

Building of the form looks the same as you have in your ts, i.e:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.extrudedHeightForm = new FormGroup({
    extrudedHeight: new FormControl()
  });
}
```

and setting the value:

```ts
this.extrudedHeightService.getExtrudedHeight("default").subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.extrudedHeightForm.get('extrudedHeight').setValue(data.extrudedHeight);
});
```

In the above, don't use `any` as the type, but instead type your data as an interface or class.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got some understanding because of your answer.

Comment: @rosd I see you accepted the answer using both ngModel and formcontrolname together. Just want to mention this is deprecated and will be removed in Angular version 7. ngModel and formcontrol isn't supposed to be used together, and in the future you would have to choose either template driven or reactive form :)